# like somebody doing something

Tags: grammaticality

I didn't like ***him*** taking all the credit.

Would you please show me some more other examples in such a way that I could get its concept or construction better?-- although I almost know what this sentence means.

What is more, I am wondering if we must use always pronounce after like or we could use any subject.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question, "What is more, I am wondering if we must use *always pronounce* after like or we could use any subject."  The part in italics is particularly problematic.  We do always use this construction for this particular type of sentence.  Subject-doesn't like-object-gerund.  *She doesn't like people touching her things.* or *Dad didn't like John enlisting.*  I think I'm going to post this as an answer and adapt it if your comments suggest it needs it.

Comment: Pronouns- I, he, she, it, we, they... Pronounce - how you say a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of sentence is used to indicate our feelings either about an action, though the construction is used in a number of other cases as well.  (ex: I saw him playing at the park.)

In general,

> Subject (doesn't) like/love/hate/enjoy/etc Object Gerund.

Examples:

> Bill likes puppies playing.

In general, Bill enjoys watching dogs play.

> She despises people touching her things.

In general, she gets very upset when people touch her things.

> Dad didn't like John enlisting.

John has joined the military and Dad is unhappy about that fact.

> Fathers often don't like their daughters dating.

In general, many fathers are not happy that their daughters go on dates.

Using the possessive is more natural in some cases, but it has a slightly different meaning.

> 1 - Bill likes Sarah singing. 
>  2 - Bill likes Sarah's singing.

Sentence 1 means that Bill likes the fact that Sarah is singing.  Perhaps she was shy, but now that she has sung in public she is less so and sings more often now.  It doesn't mean that Sarah's voice is pleasant, necessarily, only that the act of her singing brings Bill pleasure.

Sentence 2 means that Bill enjoys the actual music that Sarah produces.

Answer (score 0):

You can put many different kinds of words after *like*:

I don't like running.

I don't like coffee.

I don't like him.

I don't like your attitude.

I don't like being made to wait.

Comment: do you feel any difference? I don't like being made to wait VS. I don't like being kept waiting